# Finding unique records from a query

Tags: ms-access

I have a query called (qry_get_unique) that returns the following data

```
StockCode   BomReference
2112001       5101200
2112001       5112271
2112001       5113015
2112001       5113033
2112002       5112273
2112002       5113034
2112003       5101201
2112003       5109200
2112003       5112272
2112003       5112321
```

I have a table(tbl_finished_items) with the following information

```
STOCK_CODE
5112321
5112272
5109200
```

I want to return StockCode and BomReference from qry_get_unique where StockCode Does not equal STOCK_CODE.

The expected results from this query would be;

```
StockCode   BomReference
2112001       5101200
2112001       5112271
2112001       5113015
2112001       5113033
2112002       5112273
2112002       5113034
2112003       5101201
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from qry_get_unique 
where StockCode not in 
    (select STOCK_CODE from tbl_finished_items)
```

Explanations:

Step 1: Access execute "select STOCK_CODE from tbl_finished_items"

Step 2: Access execute the main query and exclude results that matches with the "not in" condition

Step 3: Access return the values.